# How to create a custom find function?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, lambda

I want to create a find function which works according to a given lambda expression and matches a given character (which varies).
I tried using a lambda expression, but the matching in the lambda expression is with a constant character. I cannot vary the lambda expression according to my will.

I have a `vector < pair <char, char> > r`.
What I want to do is,

Run through this vector and see if any `r[i].second` matches with my given character. Here, the given character is part of a string and hence changes with the iteration, so I cannot fix it in the lambda expression, neither can I pass an argument to the lambda expression to figure that out.

```
bool findfn (pair <char, char> x)
{
    return x.second == mychar // I want to pass mychar as argument 
}
```

One possibility is using a lambda expression, which is explained in vincentp's answer. Can we also do it using the `findfn` shown above? The calling code would look like:

`find(r.begin(), r.end(), findfn)`

Comment: Wait you can't change the lambda?  Why not? Please demonstrate with at least pseudcode what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did not know prior to posting this question the various ways we could use a lambda. (The argument in [])

Comment: Can't you use find_if  instead of find? If you do this works fine.

Comment: Do I not have to worry about the scope of `mychar` in the comparison function while using `find_if`?

Comment: With the solution I provided: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0767e5f71e82d885

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Your answer is for `find_if`. I was trying to use if with `find` and encountering weird errors.

Comment: Your question is unclear and liable to be closed. Please provide a code snippet exemplifying the typical use case, in particular it's not clear when and how the character to be matched varies.

Comment: @Walter Does it matter? I've selected an answer and it works however the character varies.

Comment: It does matter in so far as this question should be useful for others in the future, but only if it is clear. Otherwise, it should be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a lambda and capture the `mychar` variable in the lambda capture list:

```
char mychar = 'A';
// ...
auto findfn = [mychar](pair<char, char> x) -> bool { return x.second == mychar; };
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to send `mychar` to the function?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan What you're saying is rather unclear. Can you edit your question to show how you'd want the calling code to look? It can be pseudo-code.

Comment: @vincentp if you capture `mychar` by reference, then it will even respond to changes in `mychar`, which I understood the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then `std::bind` could solve your problem. It basically takes a function, binds some values to certain parameters and returns a function which expects fewer parameters.
Example:

```
#include <functional>
//...
auto findfn = [](pair<char,char> x, char mychar) { return x.second == mychar };
char yourchar = 'a';
find_if(r.begin(), r.end(), std::bind(findfn, std::placeholder::_1, yourchar));
```

Edit: In my defense, you stated that you want to pass an additional parameter. If you can use the capture list, this would be easier of course but the approach with `std::bind` is more general.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that accepts `mychar` and returns a lambda function that uses `mychar`:

```
std::function<bool(std::pair<char, char>)> findFor(char mychar)
{
    return [mychar](std::pair<char, char> x) { return x.second == mychar; };
}

it = find_if(r.begin(), r.end(), findFor('a'));
```